# Simple update set postgres stored procedure

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-update, plpgsql

I've a problem trying to make my stored procedure work.

This is my problem:
I have a table with a columns called `a`, in this column there are telephone numbers.

I have to add `0039` if the number starts with `1`,`8`,`3` or `0` (or leave it as is if not) and store the new number in the column b.

This is my code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upg_table() RETURNS void AS $$ 
BEGIN
IF (substring(a from 0 for 2)!='00') 
  AND (substring( a from 0 for 1)='3') 
  OR (substring(a from 0 for 1)='0') 
  OR (substring(a from 0 for 1)='1') 
  OR ( substring(a from 0 for 1)='8') 
THEN 
UPDATE cdr 
SET
     b = '0039'||a;
ELSE
UPDATE cdr 
SET
  b = a;
END IF;
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error is:

> ERROR:  the column  "a" does not exist
>   ROW 1: SELECT substring(a from 0 for 2)!='00' AND ...

Comment: At first glance your boolean logic looks out of whack.  You should put parenthesis around your ideas.  Like `(sub1 AND sub2) OR (sub3 AND sub4)`

Comment: Your error comes from the fact that you dont declare or pull `a` from anywhere.  I think you need to change your if statement into a `select case`.

Comment: In your `if` statement you can only reference variables or parameters. But you neither have a variable named `a` nor a parameter named `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code has two errors:

- You cannot reference the column `a` like it was a (non-existent) plpgsql variable. You would have to loop, too. Your approach does not work *at all*.
- You got [operator precedence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE) wrong. `AND` binds before `OR`.

But most importantly, you don't need a plpgsql function. A plain `UPDATE` will do the job:

```
UPDATE cdr
SET    b = CASE WHEN left(a, 1) IN ('0', '1', '3', '8')
                 AND left(a, 2) <> '00'
           THEN '0039' || a ELSE a END;
```

This updates `b` in *all* rows, but only some with a changed `a`.